# Can SimpleDateFormat print the time zone?

Tags: java, datetime

If I want my formatted date to look like:

`2021-07-21 2:02:08.483 p.m. EDT`

Can the `SimpleDateFormat` class print "EDT" or "EST", without me hard-coding it? What would be the format specifier? So far I have:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS a`

Comment: Yes, SimpleDateFormat provides timezone format characters.  Look here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.  Also consider Java8 [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I should have looked here first.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZonedDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd H:mm:ss a zzz", Locale.CANADA);
        String strDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(dtf);
        System.out.println(strDateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-21 10:34:12 a.m. EDT
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/aLz2a3)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Just for the sake of completeness

Just for the sake of completeness, given below is the solution using `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss a zzz", Locale.CANADA);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        String strDateTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(strDateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-21 10:36:52 a.m. EDT
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/IXYWhi)

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm working with some legacy code that uses java.util.Date throughout, but I'm accepting your answer because you gave me the abbreviation for the time zone. Appreciate it!

Comment: @CNDyson - No worries. I've added a solution using `SimpleDateFormat` as well. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `z` to your pattern - but next time, [refer to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Got it. But if I use a "z", how to specify that I want the abbreviation "EDT", and not "Eastern Daylight Time"?